# GraphClient -> delete user => Insufficient privileges

Tags: .net, azure, microsoft-graph-api, azure-ad-b2c

I'm trying to delete user from azure b2c using graph client

```
 await _serviceClient.Users[userId].Request().DeleteAsync();
```

but following error is thrown

```
 Status Code: Forbidden
  Microsoft.Graph.ServiceException: Code: Authorization_RequestDenied
  Message: Insufficient privileges to complete the operation.
  Inner error:
    AdditionalData:
    date: 2023-08-20T18:31:21
    request-id: 9a8594da-0fdd-4eb1-9f75-f9c60e59e3e8
    client-request-id: 9a8594da-0fdd-4eb1-9f75-f9c60e59e3e8
  ClientRequestId: 9a8594da-0fdd-4eb1-9f75-f9c60e59e3e8
```

I have following permissions granted to microsoft graph.
Am I missing something?
[image]

> graph client works as expected in other scenarios (get, update, create
> users).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error usually occurs if the service principal does not have proper **roles** or **permissions** to perform the operation.

I registered one Azure AD B2C application and granted **API permissions** as below:

[image]

When I ran below code to delete b2c user, I too got **same error**:

```cs
using Azure.Identity;
using Microsoft.Graph;
using Microsoft.Graph.Models;
using Microsoft.Kiota.Abstractions;
using Microsoft.Graph.Models.ODataErrors;
using System;

var scopes = new[] { "https://graph.microsoft.com/.default" };

var clientId = "appId";
var tenantId = "tenantId";
var clientSecret = "secret";

var options = new ClientSecretCredentialOptions
{
    AuthorityHost = AzureAuthorityHosts.AzurePublicCloud,
};

var clientSecretCredential = new ClientSecretCredential(
    tenantId, clientId, clientSecret, options);

var graphClient = new GraphServiceClient(clientSecretCredential, scopes);

try
{
    await graphClient.Users["userId"].DeleteAsync();
    Console.WriteLine("User deleted successfully!");
}

catch (ODataError odataError)
{
    Console.WriteLine(odataError.Error.Code);
    Console.WriteLine(odataError.Error.Message);
}
```

**Response:**

[image]

> In **app-only** scenarios, the *User.ReadWrite.All* application permission isn't enough privilege to delete users with privileged administrative roles.
>
> To **resolve** the error, the app must be assigned a higher privileged
> administrator role like *User Administrator* or *Global Administrator*.

In my case, I assigned **User Administrator** role to the application like below:

[image]

When I ran the same code again after few minutes, I got **response** saying user deleted successfully:

```cs
using Azure.Identity;
using Microsoft.Graph;
using Microsoft.Graph.Models;
using Microsoft.Kiota.Abstractions;
using Microsoft.Graph.Models.ODataErrors;
using System;

var scopes = new[] { "https://graph.microsoft.com/.default" };

var clientId = "appId";
var tenantId = "tenantId";
var clientSecret = "secret";

var options = new ClientSecretCredentialOptions
{
    AuthorityHost = AzureAuthorityHosts.AzurePublicCloud,
};

var clientSecretCredential = new ClientSecretCredential(
    tenantId, clientId, clientSecret, options);

var graphClient = new GraphServiceClient(clientSecretCredential, scopes);

try
{
    await graphClient.Users["userId"].DeleteAsync();
    Console.WriteLine("User deleted successfully!");
}

catch (ODataError odataError)
{
    Console.WriteLine(odataError.Error.Code);
    Console.WriteLine(odataError.Error.Message);
}
```

**Response:**

[image]

In your case, make sure to assign proper **directory** role to the application like *User Administrator* or *Global Administrator* to resolve the error.

**Reference:**
[Delete a user - Microsoft Graph API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/user-delete?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http#permissions)